# ArcGIS Javascript API: Force the fit option when zooming via rubberband selection with tiled map services

Tags: web-mapping, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

We're using ESRI's ArcGIS Javascript API with a tiled basemap and when the user zooms in using a rubberband selection via the navigation toolbar the map sometimes zooms in too far.  This is apparently expected behaviour (not sure why!) when using the API with a tiled map service.  However, we need to change this behaviour since this is a usability issue.

When calling `map.setExtent()` directly it's possible to change the default behaviour by specifying the `fit` option.  Eg. `map.setExtent(extent, true)`.  Unfortunately, we can't find a way to specify this option when zooming using the Navigation toolbar.  The only way to fix this that we could find was by overriding `setExtent()` in a custom sub-class of `esri.Map`.  We ended up having to override the `setLevel()` method as well because just blindly setting the `fit` option to `true` inside our `setExtent()` method caused the `setLevel()` method to fail as the zoom level was sometimes overridden.

Functional workaround:

```
dojo.declare("MyMap", esri.Map, {
  levelling : false,

  setExtent : function(extent, fit) {
    var shouldfit = fit;
    if (fit === undefined && !this.levelling) { 
      shouldfit = true; 
    }
    this.inherited(arguments, [extent, shouldfit]);
  },

  setLevel : function(level) {
    this.levelling = true;
    try { 
      this.inherited(arguments); 
    }
    finally { 
      this.levelling = false; 
    }
  }
});
```

I'm not happy with the workaround above and feel we must be missing an obvious, simple way to change the zoom behaviour to use the `fit` option without resorting to the hack above.  Does anyone know of a better way?